# Set value of "Search Box" empty in datatable by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, datatable

I want to set value of "Search Text Box" empty in datatable with the help of jquery .val() but it is not setting. How can i set value of text box empty in onClick function.

[Check Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bg0DT.png)

Comment: If you need an answer you have to put some code to describe your current tests.

Comment: we need a bit more information please

Comment: In datatable i want search value blank on click of button.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to trigger `keyUp` event; like so:

```
$('input[type="search"]').val('').keyup()
```

The listener function that filters data table is binded to keyup event.

Answer (score 0):

Same idea as above

```
$('#table-search-clear-filter').on('click', function() {
    $('#table-search').val('');
});
```

And to respond to above comment an id for a dataTable is made as `your-datatable-name_filter`

Answer (score 0):

When you set data input Then call it function 
For Example: i want search somthing like this => get data in input and search in datatable
when put data in searcher datatable in code **call it function with keyup()**

```
<table id="user_data">
<input id="day"  onchange="onSelectDay(this.value)" placeholder="get_data_from_user_and_put_in_searcher_datatable "/>
 </table>
 <script>
 function onSelectDay(str) 
 var date = document.getElementById("day").value;       
 $("input[aria-controls=user_data]").val(date).keyup(); //this input create auto in datatable
 </script>
```